# Add data in Sequelize migration script?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can I add data to a table in a Sequelize migration script?
This is what I got:

```
module.exports = {
up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.createTable(
        'person',
        {
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            age: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        {
            charset: 'latin1' // default: null
        }
    );
    // I want to insert person and age.
    migration.insert(???);
    done()
},
down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.dropTable('queue');
    done()
}
```

}

Answer (score 19):

I figured it out. Sequelize is available from *migration.migrator.sequelize*. It is possible to do something like this:

```
up: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.createTable(
        'Person',
        {
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        }
    ).success(function () {
        migration.migrator.sequelize.query("insert into person (name, age) values ('Donald Duck', 60)");
        done();
    });
},
down: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.dropTable(
      'Person'
    ).then(function() {
      done();
    })
}
```

Comment: These queries return promises. You'll want to not call `done()` until after the promise is satisfied, otherwise your next migration might fail. 

`migration.dropTable('Person').then(function(){done()})`

Comment: `migration.migrator.sequelize.query` should be `migration.sequelize.query` now

Answer (score 12):

In the latest version of sequelize this has changed and it should now be

```
migration.createTable(
    'Person',
    {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }
).then(function () {
    migration.sequelize.query("insert into person (name, age) values ('Donald Duck', 60)");
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually it is not a good idea to just run a query. queryInterface has create() and bulkCreate() now.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('roles', [{
      label: 'user',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }, {
      label: 'admin',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }]);
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('roles', null, {});
  }
};
```

This returns a promise as expected by sequelize-cli.

Source (adapted): https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3210

Comment: Thanks for this. This answers how to insert data, but what is the right way to get data first? For example, I'm trying to insert data into a new table from two columns that I am dropping in another table.

Comment: Thank you! This is the updated / recent way to do it!

Answer (score 6):

In sequelize version 4.41.2, when you use ES6+ and you want to do more complex insertions within migration you could make the `up` an async function which
creates your table and then inserts the necessary data into the table. To ensure that the migration either succeeds OR fails without making any changes a transaction is used for every
interaction with sequelize. Another important thing to note is that `up` must return a Promise.

Example of creating a table -> fetching data from other table -> modifying fetched data -> inserting modified data to new table:

```
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable('person', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
            },
            age: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
            },
        }, { transaction });
        // Returns array [[results], { /** result obj */ }]
        const [dogs] = await queryInterface.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM public."Dogs";', { transaction });
        // prepare data
        const metamorphed = dogs.map(({ name, age }) => ({
            name,
            age: parseInt((age * 7), 10),
        }));
        return queryInterface.bulkInsert('person', metamorphed, { transaction });
    }),
    down: queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('person'),
};
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that there's no workaround for the raw SELECT queries currently it seems: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/862 I alwo added a `bulkUpdate` example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898994/bulkupdate-in-sequelize-orm/69044138#69044138

Answer (score 0):

I'm Solution. this is an example:

```
    "use strict";

    module.exports = {
        up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface
                .createTable("roles", {
                    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
                    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
                    description: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
                })
                .then(() => {
                    queryInterface.bulkInsert("roles", [{
                            name: "admin",
                            description: "Admins",
                        },
                        {
                            name: "company",
                            description: "Companies",
                        },
                        {
                            name: "user",
                            description: "Users",
                        },
                    ]);
                });
        },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable("roles");
    },
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).