# Sequelize Migration: update model after updating column attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I will get through to the point already. I'm having a problem of updating the rows after I have changed the status column attribute.

```
up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.changeColumn('projects', 'status', {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('processing', 'unassigned', 'ongoing', 'completed'),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'unassigned'
    }).then(function() {
        return Project.update({
            status: 'unassigned'
        }, {
            where: {
                status: 'processing'
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The Project.update() seems not working in any case but changing the attributes of the column works.

Any idea guys? I'm somehow a newbie in sequelize and any idea would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742962/add-data-in-sequelize-migration-script The feature request: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/862

Answer (score 16):

Depending on how you execute the migration ( via `sequelize-cli` or programmatically via umzug ). There is a different way to expose the table via the ORM.

In your case you have `queryInterface` passed as an argument to your function. So you can do a "raw query" via the attached `sequelize` property.

```
up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.changeColumn('projects', 'status', {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('processing', 'unassigned', 'ongoing', 'completed'),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'unassigned'
    }).then(function() {
        return queryInterface.sequelize
                             .query("UPDATE projects SET status='unassigned' WHERE status='processing'");
    });
}
```

By doing this you will make a raw Query to your database.

You can check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jonyrock/324d2d3e2ab7e305774fc674bb60bd90) for more details on an advanced way of using the ORM inside the migration.

I'm a fan of using [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) programmatically, which executes the migrations and also provides the initialized models of your database. If you configure it properly, you will benefit the exposed models ( e.g. `sequelize.model('project').update()` ) and have a better looking code.