# bulkUpdate in sequelize orm

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How can we implement bulkUpdate like bulkCreate in sequelize orm,
I searched the whole documentation of sequelize but didn't find anything related to bulkUpdate,
so I tried to loop update in for loop, it works but is there any other way to update in bulk

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the bulkCreate to bulkUpdate method.

```
bulkCreate([...], { updateOnDuplicate: ["name"] })
```

`updateOnDuplicate` is an array of fields that will be updated when the primary key (or may be unique key) match the row. Make sure you have at least one unique field (let say id) in your model and in the `dataArray` both for upsert.

For reference [refer here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

Comment: does not work for MS SQL. sequelize throws an error: `mssql does not support the updateOnDuplicate option.`

Comment: "only supported by MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite >= 3.24.0 & Postgres >= 9.5" - from docs: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate

Comment: Here's an updated link https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-bulkCreate

Answer (score 36):

You can, if you want to update a lot of records with the same values!
example:
I want to update field "activationStatus" for 10 users at 1 time,
1 user = 1 record in DB and I have Array of user IDs then:

```
User.update({ activationStatus: 'active'}, {
          where: {
              id: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
          }
      });
```

it will be analogue of SQL query:

```
UPDATE User SET activationStatus = 'active' WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

you can find more info about  Sequelize Operator Aliases [HERE](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html#operators-security:%7E:text=operatorsAliases%20%3D%20%7B,-%24eq)

Comment: And you can also update fields based on other fields which is supported by SQL, example at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69044138/895245

Comment: how would you write this query for update user set usename = a for id =1 username = b for id = 2......and so on

Comment: @PirateApp query mentioned by you is imposible in sequelize

Answer (score 5):

**Minimal `bulkCreate` + `updateOnDuplicate` example**

Just to clarify what was mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900639/895245

```
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.' + path.basename(__filename) + '.sqlite',
});

(async () => {
const Integer = sequelize.define('Integer',
  {
    value: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: true, // mandatory
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    inverse: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
await Integer.sync({force: true})
await Integer.create({value: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'});
await Integer.create({value: 3, inverse: -3, name: 'three'});
await Integer.create({value: 5, inverse: -5, name: 'five'});

// Initial state.
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).name, 'two');
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).name, 'three');
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).name, 'five');
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, -3);
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, -5);
assert.strictEqual(await Integer.count(), 3);

// Update.
await Integer.bulkCreate(
  [
    {value: 2, name: 'TWO'},
    {value: 3, name: 'THREE'},
    {value: 7, name: 'SEVEN'},
  ],
  { updateOnDuplicate: ["name"] }
);

// Final state.
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).name, 'TWO');
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).name, 'THREE');
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).name, 'five');
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 7 } })).name, 'SEVEN');
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, -3);
assert.strictEqual((await Integer.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, -5);
assert.strictEqual(await Integer.count(), 4);

await sequelize.close();
})();
```

Generated SQLite update query:

```
INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` (`value`,`name`) VALUES (2,'TWO'),(3,'THREE'),(7,'SEVEN')
  ON CONFLICT (`value`) DO UPDATE SET `name`=EXCLUDED.`name`;
```

**Minimal `update` example**

To complement what was mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63727529/895245 you don't need to use fixed values for update, you can also use other columns and SQL functions, e.g.:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');

const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.' + path.basename(__filename) + '.sqlite',
});

(async () => {
const Inverses = sequelize.define('Inverses',
  {
    value: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    inverse: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false }
);
await Inverses.sync({force: true})
await Inverses.create({value: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'});
await Inverses.create({value: 3, inverse: -3, name: 'three'});
await Inverses.create({value: 5, inverse: -5, name: 'five'});

// Initial state.
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, -3);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, -5);
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

// Update to fixed value.
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: 0, },
  { where: { value: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, 0);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, 0);
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

// Update to match another column.
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.col('value'), },
  { where: { value: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, 3);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, 5);
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

// Update to match another column with modification.
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.fn('1 + ', sequelize.col('value')), },
  { where: { value: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, 4);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, 6);
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

// A string function test.
await Inverses.update(
  { name: sequelize.fn('upper', sequelize.col('name')), },
  { where: { value: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).name, 'two');
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).name, 'THREE');
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).name, 'FIVE');
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

await sequelize.close();
})();
```

Generated SQLite update queries:

```
UPDATE `Inverses` SET `inverse`=$1 WHERE `value` > 2
UPDATE `Inverses` SET `inverse`=`value` WHERE `value` > 2
UPDATE `Inverses` SET `inverse`=1 + (`value`)
UPDATE `Inverses` SET `name`=upper(`name`) WHERE `value` > 2
```

**`QueryInterface.bulkUpdate` minimal example for a migration**

What was confusing me is that there is [a `bulkUpdate` for `QueryInterface`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-bulkUpdate), but there isn't one [for `Model`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html).

Part of the reason seems to be that there is no way to make non-raw queries in migrations as mentioned at: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/862 With the non-raw queries, we can just use `.update` as shown above. It appears that this `bulkUpdate` is a more raw version that is available to migrations.

A full example is shown at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirodown/blob/bulk-update-col/web/migrations/20210903000000-user-add-display-name-column.js In this example, I was adding a new `displayName` column to the database, and I wanted it to be based on the existing `username` column.

Here's an example of how to do it to make `displayName` be the same as `username`. Note how it is not actually using an Array input like `Model.bulkCreate`, it just runs an SQL `UPDATE` query instead, so the naming is a bit confusing:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
    await queryInterface.addColumn('User', 'displayName',
      {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(256),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: '',
      },
      {transaction},
    )
    await queryInterface.bulkUpdate('User',
      {displayName: queryInterface.sequelize.col('username')},
      {}, // optional where clause to select which rows to update
          // If empty like this it updates every single row.
      {transaction},
    )
  }),
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('User', 'displayName')
  }
};
```

Related example for creation: [Add data in Sequelize migration script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742962/add-data-in-sequelize-migration-script/54445604#54445604)

**TODO `QueryInterface.bulkInsert` + `updateOnDuplicate` minimal example for a migration**

OK, so now I want to actually insert an array during migration, since my modification is just too complex, and cannot be done inside SQL with `bulkUpdate`: I have to bring data into Node and then push it back.

I would expect the following would work, but it didn't, and given the complete lack of backtraces... I'm not sure why:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
    await queryInterface.addColumn('User', 'displayName',
      {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(256),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: '',
      },
      {transaction},
    )
    const [users] = await queryInterface.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM "User";', { transaction });
    const newUsers = users.map(user =>
      { return { id: user.id, displayName: user.username } }
    )
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert('User',
      newUsers,
      {
        updateOnDuplicate: ['displayName'],
        transaction,
      }
    )
  }),
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('User', 'displayName')
  }
};
```

fails with:

```
ERROR: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Tested on sequelize 6.5.1, sqlite3 5.0.2, node v14.17.0, Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: in order to see a stack trace in a migration you have to surround everything in a try catch statement: `async up(blah){ try { await queryInterface.... } catch (err) {log it}`