# Sequelize bulkcreate is throwing error that syntax error at or near ")"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Here I am updating `user_features` in database and I found from [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900639) that I can Bulk update through `updateOnDuplicate:` But it's throwing error like below

```
  SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near ")"
```

I have tried `updateOnDuplicate: true` but it only supports in mysql not in postgresql

```
var feature_body_list = [];

        for (let index = 0; index < req.body.features.length; index++) {
            let feature_body = {
                user_id: req.body.id,
                feature_id: req.body.features[index]
            }
            feature_body_list.push(feature_body);
        }

        await sequelize.user_features.bulkCreate(feature_body_list, { updateOnDuplicate: ["user_id", "feature_id"] });
```

but when I remove updateonDuplicate it works perfectly and throws UniqueConstraintError  duplication of key
so, how can I bulk update ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try To update your [Sequelize.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) Version to latest version. I think it will solve your problem. I have also faced same error I have updated my Sequelize.js version to latest version