# Update several records at once with different values with sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a RESTful API. I'm trying to update several records saved in my MySQL database with different values each one. I'm developing it through of Sequelize.

```
const input = [
  {
    id: 'id-1',
    field1: 'data0',
    field2: 'data1',
    field3: 'data2',
  }, 
  {
    id: 'id-2',
    field1: 'data3',
    field2: 'data4',
    field3: 'data5',
  },
];
 
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  const element = input[i];

  await <database_manager>.<name-table>.update(element,
    { where: { id: element.id } },
  );
}
```

Is there better way to implement this type of updating? or Is the loop the better way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900639/6345936

Answer (score 2):

To update several records at once (from the same table/model) you can use the [`Model.bulkUpdate()`](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/instances.html#working-in-bulk--creating--updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once-). Note that by default the bulk hooks will run but the "individual" hooks will not, unless you specify `individualHooks: true` in the options. You may also want to specify `validate: true` to trigger any custom validators.

If you want to update multiple tables/Models at the same time you should pass them to `Promise.all()` to resolve them asynchronously. Regarding the example in your question - you generally want to avoid using `await` in a `for` loop. This will cause it to run the Promises (which are asynchronous) sequentially, effectively making them synchronous. If each db call takes 1 second, and you make 3, then the total time will be ~3 seconds. If you use the following code to run them concurrently you should see a total time of ~1sec - 3x faster.

```js
const inputs = [
  {
    model: 'TableOne',
    data: {
      id: 'id-1',
      field1: 'data0',
      field2: 'data1',
      field3: 'data2',
    },
  },
  {
    model: 'TableTwo',
    data: {
      id: 'id-2',
      field1: 'data3',
      field2: 'data4',
      field3: 'data5',
    },
  },
];

// loop over the inputs and return an array of promises, one for each update
const promises = inputs.map(input) => {
  const { model, data } = input;
  return db[model].update(data, { where: { id: data.id } });
});
// resolve all the db calls at once
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Thank you so much by your comment, I like the last paragraph about to use `Promise.all`. This is very fast in execution and save resource. I will use the `Promise.all`. I think that `Model.bulkUpdate` only is useful when use `Model.bulkCreate` because I looked for the example and always it show, first creation and after update.

Comment: Really helpful, simple and to the point! +1

Answer (score -1):

**To update several records at once with different values -**

Here are the possible ways:

1. **Looping with async-await** : This will cause a performance issue as the number of database queries will be N and moreover there will be sequence updates for queries not parallel.
2. **Prepare promises with iteration** : Prepare all database queries promises as presented in the answer given by @doublesharp. In this approach also N database queries will be triggered but they will get executed in parallelism so latency time will get reduced as databases are capable to handle concurrent operations.
3. **Raw SQL update query with Case-When-Then**: This is one of the efficient approache as multiple updates with different values will happen only in one query.

**Here is the example for the third approach with respect to asked question**

```
/* Custom update query to update multiple rows with different values at once */
let query = `update table_name set field1 = (case`;
inputs.forEach(input => {
  query += ` when id = ${input.id} then '${input.field1}'`
});
query += ` end) where id in (${inputs.map(input => input.id).join(',')})`;

await Sequelize.query(
  query,
  {
    bind: {
      ids: 192 // This is not used in the query but can be used to inject dynamic value if needed. And this variable will be accessed in query using $ids
    },
    type: QueryTypes.UPDATE
  }
);
```

For more information on sequelize raw queries please refer

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/

Hope this will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)