# While trying to save data from server side into MySql database, throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Using `Express` in server side and `Axios` to send res calls. While trying to save data into MySql database, I am getting below error in console: Using `sequelize.js` for model/schema creation.

Error:

```
(node:23364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.build(...).save is not a function
    at Function.create (C:\Main\Work\devchoice\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2228:8)
    at CsvParser.<anonymous> (C:\Main\Work\devchoice\src\server.js:289:60)
    at CsvParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:23364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()
```

`server.js`

```
const manageNomineesSchema = require('./server/models/managenominees');
const ManageNomineesModel  = manageNomineesSchema(sequelize, DataTypes);

    app.post('/service/managenominees', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        if(req.file){
          let filePath = req.file.path;
          fs.createReadStream(filePath)
              .pipe(csv())
              .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
              .on('end', async () => {
                console.log(results);
                let manageNominees = await ManageNomineesModel.create(results);
                //res.status(200).send(manageNominees);
                res.status(200).json({ message: "Nominees inserted successfully !"});
              });
          }
    
      } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
      }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.create` takes an object as an argument to create 1 instance, however, you are passing an array of objects.

If you would like to insert everything in the array, use `.bulkCreate`.

ref: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

Comment: Thank you very much Emma, it worked out well, upvoted and accepted!

Comment: `bulkCreate` can be also used to update. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900639/2956135

Comment: I have tried the same way, but no luck yet, it’s inserting the same records again.

Comment: Have you added PK value to the object in array and use `updateOnDuplicate`?

Comment: I have tried as per the example:’ await ManageNomineesModel.bulkCreate(allNominees,{ updateOnDuplicate: ["name"] 
                })’

Comment: I have added the table/ data image for reference. I understood ``updateOnDuplicate``  is to add which column that need to be updated ?

Comment: `allNominees` should have `id` in object to have "update" instead of "create".  like this `[{ id: 1, name: 'athbest', email: 'athin.best@test1.com' }, ...` 
The key is that you need to have PK in the object for updating.

Comment: If you are still having troubles, please open a new question.  It is diverged from the original question.

Comment: Thank you Emma, I have opened a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679986/how-can-i-bulk-update-records-using-sequelize-js-and-ignore-certain-columns